# How can I run only a single test with cypress-cucumber-preprocessor?

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I know in Cypress (like many other JS test frameworks) `.only` method is used to run only specific methods. How do I achieve the same in tests using `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was found in https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/ca368dc768ef57b2c1e5b0eb5a53826c0fa21ce0/docs/tags.md:

> In the absence of a `tags` value and presence of a scenario with `@only`, only said scenario will run. You can in other words use this tag as you would use `.only()` in Mocha.